How to migrate a Magento 2 single store to a Magento 2 multi store
What is the best method to migrate all data (Orders, Customers, Catalog, Attributes) from a single Magento 2 store instance to a new Magento 2 Multi store instance?
What is the process? or extension that you recommend

@AlfredoGM
Hey,
Do follow the following steps:
Step 1: Backup Your Data
Step 2: Create a New Website
Step 3: Create a New Store
Step 4: Create a New Store View
Step 5: Configure Store URLs
Step 6: Configure Store-Specific Settings
Step 7: Refresh Cache and Reindex
Thank You!
